# Requirements for Increasing quota as private person

Tags: youtube-api, quota

a few programmers and I want to create a new Plugin for the YouTube-Addon in Kodi (XBMC). For this Project we need a hughe increase of the Quota because we have at least 4 Million Users ([Download-counter](http://addons.kodi.tv/show/plugin.video.youtube/))
The Link above is the current plugin which we would to replace. In this plugin we allways have the problem with the quota (plugin is blocked for at least 4 hours)

Which requirements are essential for the plugin to get an increase of the quota?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be answering an [apply for addtional quota form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/) for Youtube Data API v3.

Here's the full statement [from the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota):

> If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota on the
>   Quotas tab in the Developer's Console.
>
> Note that projects that had enabled the YouTube Data API before April
>   20, 2016, have a different default quota for that API

.